# Google Map not showing,giving error of missing key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to google maps. I have added the following code to display it :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marker Clustering</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      function initMap() {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 3,
          center: {lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887}
        });

        // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
        var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

        // Add some markers to the map.
        // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
        // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
        // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
        var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
          return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            label: labels[i % labels.length]
          });
        });

        // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
            {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
      }
      var locations = [
        {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
        {lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181},
        {lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124},
        {lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834},
        {lat: -33.851702, lng: 151.216968},
        {lat: -34.671264, lng: 150.863657},
        {lat: -35.304724, lng: 148.662905},
        {lat: -36.817685, lng: 175.699196},
        {lat: -36.828611, lng: 175.790222},
        {lat: -37.750000, lng: 145.116667},
        {lat: -37.759859, lng: 145.128708},
        {lat: -37.765015, lng: 145.133858},
        {lat: -37.770104, lng: 145.143299},
        {lat: -37.773700, lng: 145.145187},
        {lat: -37.774785, lng: 145.137978},
        {lat: -37.819616, lng: 144.968119},
        {lat: -38.330766, lng: 144.695692},
        {lat: -39.927193, lng: 175.053218},
        {lat: -41.330162, lng: 174.865694},
        {lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.439506},
        {lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.501315},
        {lat: -42.735258, lng: 147.438000},
        {lat: -43.999792, lng: 170.463352}
      ]
    </script>
    <script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js">
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Key&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It is asking for the key which we have to purchase i think, up to the extent which i have researched about it. can anyone please guide how to solve this key issue or is there any other way which can be used to display the map on website. I do have created the key fromgoogle cloud platform and puted it in required place still the code just shows a glimpse of map and then disappears giving the error for key.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is impossible to reproduce the error with the given code. What key did you generate and how? What is the "required place" for the key that you mentioned? What about sharing the exact and complete error that you receive?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Answer (score 1):

Since you already generated an API key from [Google Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/), kindly make sure of the following:

**A**. Include the API key from the GCP Console like the sample shown below:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Aiza*******&callback=initMap"></script>
```

**B.** Make sure that you have a valid billing account associated to the project where your API key belongs.

- If you do not enable your billing account, you will only be able to load your map once per day.
- Do not be afraid to add your billing account as you will not be charged unless you upgrade your billing account.
- Upon enabling your billing account, you will be entitled to a one time $300 free credit(usable for Google Cloud Platform products) and a monthly recurring $200 free credit(exclusive for Google Maps Platform), in case that you exhaust the free credits, you will receive an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error and will not be charged, if you wish to not interrupt your usage, you may upgrade your billing account and you will be billed accordingly after you consume all your free credits.

Note: Please also be sure to enable the [Maps Javascript API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/maps-backend.googleapis.com) as well.

Comment: Is there any other way to use maps without the Key or without using the googleMapApI. what are the other possible ways to highlight a specific area map on my website?

Comment: Currently, all Google Maps API requires the use of API key, if you will just need to show a specific area in a map, you may try embedding [Google My Maps](https://www.google.com/mymaps) in your website, you will just need to create the map that you'd like to be shown in your site and get the embed link for your site. this way, you will not need to obtain an API key as this does not require you an APiI key to include in your website.

Comment: ok thanks for clarifying. i will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the key parameter from the following resource.

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
```

It will render the map in development environment. So, that you can develop whatever you want in the development mode.

I have developed google map web application without the key parameter (development environment) which works perfectly.

[image]

The map will show the message FOR DEVELOPMENT PURPOSE ONLY in development environment.

Comment: Some functionality provided by the API requires you to use a key. Whether you are developing or not. So this is not an appropriate solution, and certainly not a long term solution.

Comment: definitely it is not a long term solution. but for development it may b ok.

Comment: That's not an appropriate answer

Comment: is it possible to show markers in this "development purpose mode"?